# Rails : migration for creating a fixed-length char(12) column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

What is the best way to define a fixed-length SQL column (CHAR(12) for instance) through a Rails migration ?

Why this should not handled by the model is because of the performance of char() vs varchar(), and I'd like to avoid injecting raw SQL in the database.

Edit : I know the :limit modifier, however the field is still varchar (which is bad for performance) and does not allow a minimum size.

Comment: Please note that using `char(n)` column gives no performance boost in many RDBSes (for example in Postgres, refer [their docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-character.html)). What's more, `char(n)` does not ensure minimum length (too short strings will be padded with trailing spaces) – you should use CHECK constraint instead.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If Rails doesn’t understand the column type, it’ll pass it straight through to the database. So if you want a char instead of varchar, just replace:

```
t.column :token, :string
```

With:

```
t.column :token, "char(12)"
```

Of course, this may or may not make your migrations non-portable to another database.

(credit to http://laurelfan.com/2010/1/26/special-mysql-types-in-rails-migrations)

Comment: this generates another column name char(12) for rails 4, not working anymore

Comment: Works for current Postgres too. Thank you.

Answer (score 28):

```
 def self.up
    add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25)
 end

 def self.down
    remove_column("admin_users", "username")
 end
```

Comment: I know the :limit modifier, however the field is still varchar (which is bad for performance) and does not allow a minimum size.

Comment: See a section Database Mapping http://www.dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations. As I see database field type depends on kind of database server.

Comment: This is the most advisable solution. `char(n)` does *not* ensure minimum length (at least not in many RDBSes), you should use CHECK constraint instead.

Answer (score 8):

You can use string type with limit option in your migration file like this:

```
t.string :name, :limit => 12, :null => false
```

Comment: this creates a VARCHAR

Answer (score 6):

For a database specific type, we can now use:

```
t.column(:column_name, 'char(12)')
```

And for a complete example:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     create_table :foo do |t|
       t.column(:column_name, 'custom_type')

       t.timestamps
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: this was the solution